# Proving that $2^n$ does not divide $n!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

How can prove that $2^n \nmid n!$
using binary representation for $n!$ and $2^n$.

Comment: "How many proofs exist" is not a well-defined question.  Please try to edit your question to be clearer about what you are asking.  This site is for concrete, answerable questions based on actual problems you face.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  (You might also want to explain why you think this question is on-topic for CS.SE, and isn't just a generic math question.)

Comment: It *is* a pure mathematics question, even though it may have applications in CS. (Which you don't state; that fact that both functions appear in algorithms or data structures alone is not very convincing. When do you use the proposed property?)

Comment: Please explain in what way you would like answers to be influenced by "computer science". The highest-voted answer currently uses no facts from computer science whatsoever; as it is, the question can be pretty convincingly answered as such. Please provide additional details as to why this is a computer science question. Otherwise, we can migrate to Math. Thanks for your cooperation and participation. Please visit CS chat to discuss if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working in counting *how many trailing zeros has $n!$ in base-2*, it'll be $d$.
Because, trailing zeros means that you can divide $n!$ by 2, $d$ times.

$$ n! = \underbrace{****1\overbrace{0000\cdots 000}^{d\text{ zeros}}}_{\lfloor \log n!\rfloor + 1 \ \text{ digits}}\ \  \Rightarrow \, 2^{d}\, \vert\, n!\ \ \ \ \text{ with *}\in \{0,1\}$$

So, If $T(n)$ counts trailing zeros for $n!$.

$$ T(0) = 1\ \ \ T(1) = 0 \ \ \ T(n) = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$$

Or it could be 
$$ T(n) = \sum _{i=1}^{\log n} \left \lfloor \frac{n }{2^i} \right \rfloor$$

So, there is a counterexample, consider it, $n=2^k$

$$ 
\begin{align}
T(n) &=  \sum _{i=1}^{\log n} \left \lfloor \frac{2^k}{2^i} \right \rfloor =\sum _{i=1}^{k}  2^{k-i}  = \sum _{i=1}^{k}  2^{k-i} = 2^k \left ( \sum _{i=1}^{k}  2^{-i} \right )\\
& = 2^k \left( \frac{(1/2)-(1/2)^{k+1}}{1 - (1/2)} \right) = \frac{2^{k-1} - 1/2}{1/2} = 2^k -1
\end{align}
$$

then $2^{k} - 1\ \vert\ n!$, and for that $2^{n} \not\vert\ n!$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A011371

Answer (score 5):

Idea: Count explicitly how many factors $2$ the numbers in $[1..n]$ contribute to $n!$.

Observe that every other number adds one (the even numbers), every fourth adds another (those divisible by four), every eighth another, and so on.
Hence, the number $\#_2(n!)$ of factors $2$ in $n!$ fulfills

$\qquad\displaystyle\begin{align*}
  \#_2(n!) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)} \frac{n}{2^i} \\
           &= n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)} \frac{1}{2^i} \\
           &= n \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \\
           &= n-1 \;.
\end{align*}$

Therefore, $2^n$ can not be a divisor of $n!$.

Comment: This answer has been rendered obsolete by an edit to the question.